# How to include php file in javascript's object property value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, object, include

I'm trying to modify an object's value & as my knowledge on JS & JQuery is pretty limited, I'm troubled on how to make it work.

Here is my code:

```js
var ProductData = {

  "Product1":"<li>some html</li>"
  
  "Product2":"<li>some more html</li>"
}

function loadData(ev, itemName) {
   ev.preventDefault();

   closeMenu();
   gridWrapper.innerHTML = '';
   classie.add(gridWrapper, 'content-load');
   setTimeout(function() {
    classie.remove(gridWrapper, 'content-load');
    gridWrapper.innerHTML = '<ul class="products">' + dummyData[itemName] + '<ul>';
   }, 700);
  }
```

What I need is to load a php file in Product1,  instead of html code.

I've managed to do it using an iframe , like below:

```js
var ProductData = {

  "Product1":"<iframe src=\"dir/subdir/myFile.php\"></iframe>"
  
  "Product2":"<li>some more html</li>"
}
```

but I'd prefer something like php's include function if there is something similar in JS!

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  PHP runs on a server.  Javascript, with the exception of nodejs, runs in the browser.  You can generate javascript with php, but I'm not sure that's what your asking.

Comment: Sorry, but are you just trying to assign a piece of PHP code as a string as an entry in you ProductData?

Comment: @ user1582024 & @Taplar  The ProductData object  is located in a js file and is used from another script in order to load data (I'll update the code to include this script also). What I'm trying to do is to replace these data, so when the script runs instead of loading the html code that is assigned as a string to each ProductData item, to load a php file.

Comment: So your wanting the *.js file to load and then when it does, retrieve from the server the contexts of another file and put it in that variable?

Comment: @Taplar Yes! Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

For what your describing you would need to do an ajax request to retrieve the value.  Something like.

```
var ProductData = {
    Product2: '<li>some more html</li>'
}

$.get("dir/subdir/myFile.php", function(data){
    ProductData.Product1 = data;
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I've tried your suggestion and when the js file runs and I'm trying to pull Product's1 data, I get an undefined warning! It seems like the get function needs to be inside the ProductData as Product1 value, but I'm not sure if something like ` var ProductData = {                                                                                 Product1: 'get function'
    Product2: '<li>some more html</li>'
} `is possible

Comment: $.get is a jQuery method, which you are not using jquery in your code but your question is tagged as such.  Do you have jquery in your project?  Need a clearer idea if what your actually trying.

Comment: jquery-1.11.3.min.js is loaded and used in some cases in the project.

Comment: I'd need to see what your trying.  You can also check your browser developer tools network tab to make sure the request is firing, that it's going to the correct url, and see what it is returning code and response wise.

Comment: I'll make a basic codepen just for an example because I'm working on a local server and I can't provide a link of the project.

Comment: Eventually it was easier to upload a demo of the project online, so here is a link to it ... http://websters.gr/demos/demetra1/admin/ If you click "Lived" and then "Sub1" you 'll see my php file loading through an iframe, but I'd like something like "Sub2" which uses the method I've described above.